# javascript switch break unreachable code detected

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, unreachable-code

I have the following code

```
   switch (attr.templateType) {

      case 'text': return tpl_default; break;
      case 'currency': return tpl_currency; break;
      case 'percentage': return tpl_percentage; break;
      case 'latlong': return tpl_latlong; break;
      case 'tel': return tpl_phone; break;
      case 'number': return tpl_number; break;
      case 'address': return tpl_address; break;
      case 'date': return tpl_date; break;
      case 'permissions': return tpl_permissions; break;
      case 'pagination': return tpl_pagination; break;
      case 'time': return tpl_time; break;
      case 'notEmpty': return tpl_notEmpty; break;

      default: return tpl_default; break;
    }
```

and JavaScript lint tells me "unreachable code detected" for ALL the breaks.  If i take out the breaks, lint has no errors.

does anyone know why?  The code works and with out any errors.

Comment: Who is it returning to?

Answer (score 22):

why is break required after return? switch will return and break will never execute, that is why it is unreachable.

Comment: thanx, Dij and derp.  I thought break is needed on a switch no matter what...but what you are saying makes sense.  "no code will execute after return".

Answer (score 6):

you don't need break because you are returning out of the function.
No code will execute after the return